# Tell me jar files for weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, weblogic

I'm getting errors in my IDE that there is no dependent jar file for importing

```
import weblogic.websocket.ClosingMessage;
import weblogic.websocket.WebSocketAdapter;
import weblogic.websocket.WebSocketConnection;
import weblogic.websocket.annotation.WebSocket;
```

all sites gave examples with the interfaces and classes in the jar, not available to download those jar. Help me here to identify jar file for this! Many thanks

Comment: Got the answer!

WebLogic Server provides the WebLogic WebSocket API within the wlserver/server/lib/wls-api.jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to add weblogic server in eclispe server. Or you can add "wls-api.jar".

Path of jar: oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wls-api.jar

Comment: Thanks, its useful

Answer (score 0):

Manually install jar like

e.g: mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=weblogic -DartifactId=com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client -Dversion=1.4.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\webservers\bea\modules\com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client_1.4.0.0.jar